# React : set style of a children based on the prop of a parent

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui

I have below code

```
    <span className="item-toggle" onClick={toggleChecked}>
      <Checkbox toggle checked={checked} data-togglecolor={toggleColor}/>
    </span>
```

That renders to

```
<span class="item-toggle">
  <div class="ui checked fitted toggle checkbox" data-togglecolor="#9cd3dd">
    <input class="hidden" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="" checked="">
    <label></label>
  </div>
</span>
```

The Checkbox component is part of the [Semantic UI React](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/checkbox/).  I would like to use the value of the **data-togglecolor** to style my input :

```
.ui.toggle.checkbox input:checked ~ label:before {
    background-color: XXX;
}
```

I could ofcourse hardcode it like below in my CSS

```
.ui.toggle.checkbox[data-togglecolor="#9cd3dd"] input:checked ~ label:before {
    background-color: #9cd3dd;
}
```

But I was wondering how I could achieve this dynamically.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can't access props in your CSS files unless you used something like styled-components or something related, what you can do is add a style attribute to your checkbox

```js
<div class="ui checked fitted toggle checkbox" style={{backgroundColor: this.props.yourcolorprophere}}></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use styled-components ?
If so, you could override the Checkbox component to pass the background-colour to its child, just like this :

```
const Checkbox = styled(ImportedCheckbox)`
 input {
  background-color: ${p => p['data-togglecolor']};
 }
`
```